# querydsl union multiple queries in one

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, querydsl

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
    @Entity
    public class Employee{
        private Long Id;
        private String jobTitle;
        private String firstName;

        ... getters and setters
    }
```

Is it possible to do single query and return multiple sets of data? Say I have a method signature in my repository that looks like this:

```
public EmployeeQueryResult getEmployeeQuery(Long currentUserId, String jobTitle, List<String> names);
```

and I want to use this method to get the current employee by id, all employees that have a specific job title, and all employees that have a name:

```
public class EmployeeQueryResults{
    private Employee currentEmployee;
    private List<Employee> employeesWithJobTitle;
    private List<Employee> employeesWithName;

    ...
}
```

I'm asking if it is possible to use queryDSL to basically make 3 separate queries and union them together so that I can use paging on the unioned list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm asking if it is possible to use queryDSL to basically make 3 separate queries and union them together so that I can use paging on the unioned list.

No, that's not possible with Querydsl. You can write the query in such a way that it will return Employee instances that match at least one of the constraints, but the result will be a single Employee list.

Comment: but I was thinking it could be done somehow with a union. I was looking at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/Skb9Ps1bj2Q but cant decide if its what I need or not. I am still trying to figure out if it will do what I need it to do.

Comment: Or maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923560/querydsl-how-to-join-to-a-union-of-subqueries

Comment: Both are SQL query examples, you are using JPQL which is more restricted, e.g. no union.