# Unoin clause in querydsl 4.1.3?

Tags: spring, querydsl

How can I use union clause in querydsl 4.1.3?

I want just to use union clause. Need an example.

```
#sql
select * from (
   select a,b from tableA union 
   select a,b from tableB 
)
```

[QueryDSL - how to join to a union of subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923560/querydsl-how-to-join-to-a-union-of-subqueries)

I can't find SQLSubQuery class in querydsl lib(version 4.1.3)

I'm using
* spring boot
* spring-data
* querydsl(4.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly possible for QueryDSL SQL queries:

```java
QSurvey survey1 = new QSurvey("survey1");
QSurvey survey2 = new QSurvey("survey2");
QSurvey survey3 = new QSurvey("survey3");

SQLQuery<Void> query = new SQLQuery<Void>();
query.with(survey1, select(survey1.all()).from(survey1));
query.union(
        select(survey2.all()).from(survey2),
        select(survey3.all()).from(survey3));
```

The last statement returns a subquery that yields the union of the two queries.